# Cannot fix Error while fetching - React.js

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, cors

I have written this code and I am trying to fetch data, everything works fine but no data is shown and when I inspect I have this error :

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/users' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

this is my code

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export class UserComponent extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={users:[], addModalShow:false, editModalShow:false}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshList();
    }
    
    refreshList(){
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/users')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({users:data})
        });
    }

    render(){
        const {users, userId, FirstName, Username, LastName, Phone, Password, Address} = this.state;

        return(


            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Password</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {users.length>0 && users.map((user)=>(
                            <tr key={user.Id}>
                                <td>{user.Id}</td>
                                <td>{user.FirstName}</td>
                                <td>{user.LastName}</td>
                                <td>{user.Username}</td>
                                <td>{user.Password}</td>
                                <td>{user.Adress}</td>
                                <td>{user.Phone}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const element=<UserComponent></UserComponent>
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

If someone can help I'll be glad.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this  `"proxy": "http://localhost:3000",` in your front-end package.json

In order to undertand the above snippet do, you can refer [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)